# Proving $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^na_i(B_i-\frac12)\stackrel{\text{a.s.}}\longrightarrow 0$ where $B_i$s are i.i.d Bernoulli$(\frac12)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

> **Problem:**
>
> Let $\{B_n\}$ be a sequence of independent, identically distributed Bernoulli random variables of parameter $p=\frac12$. Let $\{a_n\}$ be a non-negative, non-random sequence such that $\sup\limits_{n\geq0}\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^2<\infty$ and $\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i$ converges. Prove that $\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i(B_i-\frac12)$ converges to zero almost surely.

This is an exercise in the section of "strong law of large numbers". But I only managed to prove the case when $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: How does your proof in the bounded case look? Where is the assumption used?

Comment: @lan The main idea is the following: For $M>0$ we can choose the subsequence that is larger than M, denote by $\{a_{n_k}\}$. Then by strong law of large numbers, $N^{-1}\sum_{n_k\leq N}a_{n_k}$ converges to zero a.e.. So in the summation $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i$ the $a_{n_k}$ can be replaced by $a_{n_k}-M$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are loads of ways to go about this; I think the purpose of this problem is not to *apply* a strong law of large numbers theorem, but to essentially adapt the proof to this setting.  There are many many ways to do this, but I'm gonna sketch out a sort of easy, cheap way.

**Strategy**: We're gonna let $S_n = \sum_{j = 1}^n a_j (B_j - 1/2)$ and show that $\mathbb{E}[S_n^4] \leq C n^2$ for some constant $C$.  From here, we'll get that $\mathbb{E} [(S_n / n)^4]$ is summable, which will imply that $S_n/n \to 0$ almost surely.

1. Use the assumptions on $a_n$ to show that there exists a $C$ so that $a_j \leq C \sqrt{j}$ for all $j$.
2. By expanding directly, show that $\mathbb{E}(S_n^4) \leq c_1 \sum_{j = 1}^n a_j^4 + c_2 (\sum_{j = 1}^n a_j^2)^2$ for some constants $c_1,c_2$.
3. Use the assumption that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{ j =1}^n a_j^2$ is bounded to complete the upper bound above.

Comment: Out of curiosity, at which point is the assumption that the sequence $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ converges used?
(1. and 3. only use the uniform boundedness assumption on $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2$, don't they?)

Comment: @ClementC. Good point.  I don't believe that this assumption is actually necessary.

Comment: Really a nice proof !! With your method this assumption is actually unecessary. Thanks so much !!